# How to make turtles move in one color in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I start developping with Netlogo and I face the problem that I want to make all Turtles moving in one way which has the Black Color. How can I do that ? I tried with patch-ahead but I didn't success.
Anyone have a solution ? I will be grateful.

```
to setup


clear-all
  import-drawing "patch.png"
  create-turtles 10 [set xcor -10 set ycor -13]
  ask turtles [set color white]
  ask turtles [set shape "bug"]
  reset-ticks
end




to bouge
   ask turtles[

 fd 1
 ]


end

to go
  bouge
 ask turtles  [if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 6 != black [set heading heading - 100] ]



end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex7L5.png)

Comment: import-drawing "patch.png" doesn't change the pcolor value, use 'import-pcolors "patch.png"' instead.

Comment: @Marzy Sorry for the late answer! a lot of thanks, it is really working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like these:

set black-patches patches with [pcolor =  black]

ask turtles [
  face one-of black-patches
]

Bests, Ervin